# How do i find the radius and the center of these circles

Tags: analytic-geometry

Please help me with my math Radius Homework 
Help is really appreciated!

PS: Pls Don't be bothered by my erasure on my sheet, those 4 question are unanswered.

Instructors' formula is x^2 + y^2 = r^2

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
 x^2 + y^2 &=& 49\\
 x^2 + y^2-225 &=&0\\
 3x^2+3y^2 &=& 180\\
 \frac{1}{5} x^2 + \frac{1}{5} y^2 &=& 25
\end{array}
$$

[image: a math problem Radius!]

Comment: For all four equations, you can do some algebra manipulations to get them into the standard form $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$.  Then apply the answers from your previous question.

Comment: I Appreciate all of the Replies I've been Getting in this Question and now i finally come to understand it . I thank you all for these Accurate yet understandable Teachings.

Comment: $\sqrt{25}+4$ isn't $\sqrt{29}$. Either you're not drawing the upper bars on your square root signs properly, or you're misunderstanding how square roots work.

Comment: Yes I Forgot about Square rooting. Thanks for Reminding it to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always the same technique:
all your equations have the same form  with $a,c > 0,$

$$ax^2+ay^2 = c \iff x^2+y^2 = \frac{c}{a} \ (=r^2)\iff r = \sqrt{\frac{c}{a}} $$

Example: $8x^2+8y^2 = 32 \iff x^2+y^2 = 4 \iff x^2+y^2=2^2 \iff r = 2 = \sqrt{\frac{32}{8}}$

**EDIT:Detailed explanation on how to find the center and the radius of a general circle.** The general formula for a circle in the plane of radius $r>0$ and center $(c_1,c_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ is $$(x-c_1)^2+(y-c_2)^2=r^2.\qquad (*)$$ In you exercise all the circles are centered in $(0,0)$ so the expression reduces to $$x^2+y^2 = r^2.$$
Here's a method for going from a reduced circle equation to the canonical form $(*)$. I will explain it through an example, because the most difficulty is finding the parameters.
So let us consider the equation
$$ 2x^2+2y^2-4x+12y-30=0, \qquad (1)$$
we want to rewrite it in the form of equation $(*)$. Remember that $$(a-b)^2 =a^2-2ab+b^2 \qquad (**)$$, thus we want the in front of $x^2$ and $y^2$ to be $1$, therefore let us divide equation $(1)$ by $2$, this leads to
$$ x^2-2x+y^2+6y-15=0. \qquad (2)$$
Note that if the factors in front of $x^2$ and $y^2$ are not the same, then the set of $(x,y)$ satisfying the equation is not a circle. Still by identification with equation $(**)$ we now want to know what are the terms of the form $-2ab$, i.e. if $a=x$ or $a = y$ then what is $b$ such that we find $-2ab$ in equation $(2)$. Since the only terms of degree one in $(2)$ are $-2x$ and $6y$ it is easy to see that if $a=x$, then $-2x = -2ab$ for $b=1$ and if $a=y$, then $6y=-2ab$ for $b = -3$. So, observe that 
$$(x-1)^2 = x^2-2x+1=(x^2+2x)+1 \iff x^2+2x=(x-1)^2-1$$ 
and
$$(y-(-3))^2=y^2+6x+9=(y^2+6y)+9 \iff y^2+6y=(y+3)^2-9,$$ 
Finally, substituting these relations in equation $(2)$ shows
$$(x-1)^2-1+(y+3)^2-9-15=0 \iff (x-1)^2+(y+3)^2=25.$$
So we showed that
$$2x^2+2y^2-4x+12y-30=0 \iff (x-1)^2+(y-(-3))^2=5^2,$$
and by identification with $(*)$ it follows that this is a circle with center $(c_1,c_2)=(1,-3)$ and radius $r = 5$.

Comment: Think at adding 225 on both sides of the second equation to get a form described as above.

Comment: No need to take absolute value: if $\;\frac ca<0\;$ then the equation is *not* a circle but the empty set, and if it is non-negative then the square root is automatically, by agreement, non-negative.

Comment: I completely agree with you. I have to say that I'm not always sure about which agreement are accepted or not here. Anyway it has been edited.

Comment: Can you stick with the formula, that I've gotten on my instructor, because I think I won't be having a correct solution even if I had to try it.

Also I haven't tackled or seen that kind of formula in my math subjects on the way of my high school years.

Comment: Is it what you wanted?

Comment: @Surb Yes Absolutely wanted that kind of answer.

Comment: @Surb Ok Let me try to check your answer further so I can reply A positive feedback about the answer

Comment: Sure :), just ask if something is still not clear to you.

Comment: @Surb Ok Thanks! It's Ok now I finally come to understand it just a little bit, anyway Thanks! I'll be using it in my future days Ty.

Comment: @DanielEstrella0098 I edited the answer and tried to give you a general method for every circle. I hope it is clear enough, if not post a comment.